# Why %{HTTP_HOST} doesn't work while HTTP_HOST literal string works?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-referer, http-host

I have the next Apache code to prevent hotlinking, and it works.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://itransformer.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule /usuarios/.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ - [R=404,L]
```

The questions are two:

**1**.If I change the above to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://%{HTTP_HOST}.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule /usuarios/.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ - [R=404,L]
```

it doesn't work. `%{HTTP_HOST}` is equal to `itransformer` (in my localhost), so I don't understand why it isn't working in this way.

**2**. The default 404 page is shown instead of my custom 404 page that is shown in all other 404 responses. What can be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reason why it doesn't is that you cannot use these Apache internal variables in right hand side of `RewriteCond`.
2. I just noticed `R=404`. If you need custom 404 handler then make sure you have similar line like this on top of your .htaccess:

   ```
   ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
   ```

Comment: Wow! I could be butting my head against the wall! And do you know the second question?

Comment: Yes but you didn't post any custom 404 handler that's why I couldn't give you an answer for that.